# Trying to retrieve data from sharedRDD of apache ignite context

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, ignite

I am trying to integrate apache ignite with spark and I am new to apache ignite. I want to save data in distributed cache and retrieve it.

I have created a dataframe by loading a file in spark and trying to save in cache with sharedRDD.savePairs(key,value) of Apache Ignite. Key is of type string and value is of type spark dataframe. Now I want to retrieve the stored data and print it. I am not even sure if it is actually saved with type dataframe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To retrieve data from RDD you can leverage at least one of the following ways:

1) sharedRDD.filter(...).collect() approach. As an example the code below gets all the values that contain the word "river" from the cache named "testCache"

```
val cache = igniteContext.fromCache("testCache")
val result = cache.filter(_._2.contains("river")).collect()
```

[Reading values using 'filter' method](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/ignitecontext--igniterdd#section-reading-values-from-ignite)

2) sharedRDD.sql(...) method.

```
val cacheRdd = igniteContext.fromCache("personsCache")
val result = cacheRdd.sql(
  "select name from Person where id > ? and id < ?", 10, 100)
```

[Getting values using SQL](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/ignitecontext--igniterdd#section-running-sql-queries-against-ignite-cache)

Comment: Please add the key message of the answer in your post. The external links can become invalid.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to this. Expanded my answer with examples.

Comment: This is retrieving the data it self. But the user questioned about saving Dataframe in cache, does it possible.? Can you cache dataframe it self.? or you can cache data only.? if we can, then how to retrieve it.?

Comment: @Srini it's possible to safe DataFrame in a cache but I don't see any sense in doing so. 

IgniteRDD is a shared **key-value** RDD that stores key-value tuples uniformly across a cluster. When a DataFrame is stored as a value it will be placed to a single partition of a single node just as any other value (int, String, etc.). So in case if IgniteRDD you should store actual values rather than data frames if you want to benefit from it.

If you still want to store DataFrame using IgniteRDD then you can use Spark's rdd.collect() method to get it back.